# Preferred Connection Type in PHP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, persistent

I need to ask a performance related question.
If for example, a site gets 500 or 400 visits per second, what should be the preferred mysql connection type, Persistant or NonPersistant ????
Any other recommendation for such a web site ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

non persistent is better for low CPU over head !